# PHPExcel Export HTML String is Exporting Entire HTML Page

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a table on an html page that I need to export. I have searched other examples on here but nothing that works for me.

Here is what I have.

```
$filename = "DownloadReport";
//$table = dbGrid($q);

$table = "<div><table><tbody><tr><td>cars</td><td>cars</td><td>cars</td></tr></tbody></table></div>";

$tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'html');
file_put_contents($tmpfile, $table);


$excelHTMLReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');
$objPHPExcel = $excelHTMLReader->load($tmpfile);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('anynameyouwant');

unlink($tmpfile);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '-' . date("y.m.d") . '.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit;
```

It properly downloads the file. But for some reason its saving my entire html page with javascript and css files missing. I only need to export the table string. I have a dbGrid function to create my table but for testing I have a simple table string.

How can I export just that table string, not my entire html page.

Comment: What javascript? What css? And what do either of those have to do with MS Excel files?

Comment: I mean it exports my entire html page and when I open the file it says those files are missing.

Comment: I just checked the temp and its created properly with the table string only

Comment: rather than using PHPExcel's internal functions like `$excelHTMLReader->loadIntoExisting($tmpfile, $objPHPExcel);` why don't you try using the documented method of `$objPHPExcel = $excelHTMLReader->load($tmpfile);`

Comment: But I don't see where your web page is coming from! though you're using the wrong content type for an OfficeOpenXML xlsx file

Comment: Is the Writer creating a valid OfficeOpenXML format file?

Comment: I spotted the content type after I posted. I was trying xls too. I switched to the  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested by not instantiating phpexcel first, but when I dont instanciate it first, I get Failed opening required 'Class.PHPExcel_IOFactory.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

Comment: Are you running a custom version of PHPExcel? The Autoloader should pick up regardless as long as you've included the library

Comment: Yes I was, I resolved that issue. I edited my question with what you suggested.

Comment: The error I get now is when I open the file, I get "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid."

Comment: I have a feeling that somehow it's just echoing out all your page markup before it even hits this block of code

Comment: I have output buffering turned on, and i have other phpexcel utility functions that export fine. and I'm doing this it in the exact same spot, the exact same way. Also, the temp file is being created properly so it is hitting the code..

Comment: Open the file in a text editor, and see what it contains; if you can see html markup, then something is outputting that; but that something cannot be PHPExcel, because it can't even see your html

Comment: Yeah it still has my entire html source code

Comment: ohh do I need to clear/clean the buffer before starting the export?

Comment: Yep that did it. ob_clean(); before starting the export. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Post an answer and i'l mark it.

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you! ob_clean(); did the job for me as well.